# Reading NSUserDefault bool

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, boolean

I have a problem where I'm trying to register a bool as an NSUserDefault. I then want to be able to read this bool value later on. The issue is that when I read the value its not picking it up as a `YES`.

Here is the code I use to register the value:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableDictionary *appDefaults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[appDefaults setValue:@"YES"    forKey:kShowHelp];

[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I then read the bool using the following:

```
bool showHelp = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kShowHelp];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use setValue:forKey: use setObject:forKey:

```
[appDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kShowHelp];
```

Comment: Since I'm adding the value to a dictionary (among others) I couldn't, it only offers me the option of `setValue:` and `setObject:`

Comment: You should use setObject: -- see above

Comment: When I read the bool do I need to do anything differently? I still doesn't seem to pick it up for some reason.

Comment: @JonW09 Did you change it to an NSNumber or are you still writing a string just with setObject?

Comment: I now use exactly what you provided in your answer, however I still read it the same way as in my question.

Comment: It should work. Do you have a settings bundle with this key? Are you sure the registerDefalts: call is actually being made? Is it possible that the app already set this to NO? If you've actively set this key at some point, the registerDefaults: method won't override that. Test with a string object with a new key (some random key you make up right now) and see if that gets read back correctly. Also try deleting the app and re-installing it to clear old prefs.

Comment: It was a silly mistake on my part - forgot to call the method to register the defaults! Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using `setBool:forKey`?

```
[ appDefaults setBool: YES forKey: kShowHelp ];
```

**EDIT**

Ok, since you have a dictionary, you should use a NSNumber to represent a boolean values.

**Example**

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ];

NSMutableDictionary * appDefaults = [ NSMutableDictionary dictionary ];
[ appDefaults setObject: [ NSNumber numberWithBool: YES ] forKey: kShowHelp ];

[ defaults registerDefaults: appDefaults ];
[ defaults synchronize ];
```

**EDIT 2**

Do you know you can also create a plist in your application's bundle, and register its values as defaults? Much simpler IMHO.

Comment: Since I'm adding the value to a dictionary (among others) I couldn't, it only offers me the option of `setValue:` and `setObject:`

Comment: His appDefaults is a dictionary that he's using to register the default values, so it doesn't have a setBool:forKey: method.

Comment: Use a NSValue or NSNumber for the dictionary.